# QML RotationAnimation is not rotating

Tags: qt, animation, rotation, qml

I am trying to rotate a rectangle from-to a specified angle, but I'm not sure I understand the docs.  My code below runs, and my started and completed slots print the correct angles.  But the rectangle has not rotated onscreen.  What am I missing?

```
Rectangle {
  width: 100
  height: 100
   RotationAnimation {
        id: rotateCritter
        duration: 1000
        property real lastAngle: 0
        onStarted: {
            lastAngle = to;
            console.log("Rotating from "+from+" to "+to)
        }
        onStopped: {
            console.log("Done rotating from "+from+" to "+to)
            from = lastAngle;
        }
    }
}


// On click totate the critter to the new angle
rotateCritter.to =  45
rotateCritter.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `RotationAnimation` is missing a `target`. Though it is the child of the `Rectangle`, this relationship does not automatically make the `Rectangle` the `target` of the animation; it must be explicit. I have given the `Rectangle` an `id` and `color`, and made this the `target` of the animation:

```
    Rectangle {
        id: critter
        width: 100
        height: 100
        color: "red"

        RotationAnimation {
            id: rotateCritter
            target: critter
            duration: 1000
            property real lastAngle: 0
            onStarted: {
                lastAngle = to;
                console.log("Rotating from "+from+" to "+to)
            }
            onStopped: {
                console.log("Done rotating from "+from+" to "+to)
                from = lastAngle;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another idea besides using a `RotationAnimation` object is to just animate on the Rectangle's own `rotation` property using a `Behavior`.

```
Rectangle {
    id: rect
    width: 100
    height: 100
    Behavior on rotation {
        NumberAnimation {
            duration: 1000
        }
    }
}

rect.rotation = 45   // Animates to 45 degrees

...

rect.rotation = 0    // Animates back to 0 degrees
```